# Why am I getting Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'find'?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, typeerror, methodnotfound

**Why am I getting:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method
>   'find' (anonymous
>   function):8080/twolittlesheep/js/sizeColorDependancy.js:16
>   c.event.handleajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js:63
>   c.event.add.h.handle.oajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js:56

**when I try to run a simple jQuery script?** The script falls at the line where I use the find method in the next jquery code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select#p_sizesId").change(function(){
   var $colorsSelect = $("select#p_colorsId")[0];
   $("select#p_colorsId")[0].find('option').remove().end().append('<option selected="selected" value="whatever">text</option>');
  });
});
```

In my head tag in the html I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> --%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sizeColorDependancy.js"></script>
```

*I am using Google Chrome (together with Developer Tools).*

All that I found as an explanation in another thread was that when using Chrome's developer tools, the problem arises. But I was running the code without using the Developer Tools and the same happened (the script didn't do anything => the error occurred).

Comment: why are you using [0]? as this element has an id there will not be a collection to iterate through...

Comment: @ToonMariner - when I was debugging I saw that the DOM select object is inside an array so I wrongfully presumed that I need to get first object from the array...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `[0]` you're getting the first element from the selector matches as a DOM element, not a **jQuery** object which has `.find()`, just remove `[0]`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#p_sizesId").change(function(){
   $("#p_colorsId").find('option').remove().end().append('<option selected="selected" value="whatever">text</option>');
  });
});
```

A few other notes, when using a `#id` selector, don't prefix it unless absolutely needed, it slows things down. Also since **ID's** should be unique, there *should* be no need for getting the first element. The selector should only match 1 or 0 elements. If they're *not* unique, don't use **ID's** instead use **classes**.

Comment: This solved the problem! But consider the case where you have more than one select elements with the same id. What than? And I thought that JQuery object and a javascript object would be the same. How would I convert the javascript variable: var x = $("select#p_colorsId")[0];  to a jQuery object?

Comment: @user521754 - that was the second half to the answer - you should **never** have 2 elements with the same ID in a page, you need to use classes at that point...many things depend on IDs being unique.

Comment: the question about the same id was hypothetical (I never use element's ids like that). For the other subquestion that I asked you, can you provide a link where I can read more about jQuery objects and perhaps something about conversion from js object to jQuery object?

Comment: @user521754 - I think what you're after is the first of a selector in general, you can use `.first()` or `.eq(0)` to get the first element still as a jQuery object...is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

Just make it into a jQuery object like this:

```
$($("select#p_colorsId")[0]).find('option')
```