# error in installing joomla , route.php on line 48

Tags: php, joomla

When I filled the form on first tab of installation page(configuration tab) , and press next, ajax-loader had shown and it didn,t go to next tab(database tab). In the response of POST request I see this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method InstallationApplicationWeb::getRouter() in /home/superuser/www/joomla/libraries/joomla/application/route.php on line 48
```

I download installation package from joomla.org and place it in my webroot directory without any change.

PHP 5.3.10,mysql 5.5.31,Joomla_3.1.1

Comment: There isn't anything in the install application that should be calling the method that's throwing the error you're getting.  I'd suggest re-downloading the package from joomla.org and see if you're still getting errors.

Comment: Appears to be an incompatibility between php 5.3.10 and joomla.  I upgraded to php 5.5 but should warn that that introduced other compatibility issues

Comment: @DrC no matter what php version i try ( 5.3.21, 5.4, 5.5 ) it throws that same error. what else did you try? i've tried joomla2.5, joomla3.1... 
are you using nginx?

Comment: I just went to 5.5 and had to fix some other stuff (forget what).  I don't use nginx.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you have a conflict you can follow below steps

1. First you include jQuery.
2. Then you include jQuery UI. Make sure that the versions of jQuery and jQuery UI match up.
3. Then you include more plugins, also installed on the 1.8.3 jQuery object.

Else

You can try [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327). Read the reviews you will understand how great this component is. I have been using it for a long time now.

Other than that I can not tell anything since you haven't provided any code. Also see below.

[Jquery / Handlebars error message - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'match'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330129/jquery-handlebars-error-message-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-h)

[Why am I getting Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'find'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376884/why-am-i-getting-uncaught-typeerror-object-an-htmlselectelement-has-no-metho)